# Want to clean EGR passages using shop vac, worried about debris from broken catalytic converter getting into exhaust manifold

Tags: cleaning, catalytic-converter, egr

I need to clean the EGR valve and passages on a 1998 Honda Accord 4 cylinder. Needless to say I would like to vacuum the debris out after scraping it up, the catch is that this vehicle possibly has broken substrate loose in the catalytic converter. I'm concerned that using the vacuum will bring debris up into the manifold where it might enter the engine. How likely is this scenario, and what alternative means of cleaning the passage might exist?

Comment: Rotate engine so either inlet or exhaust valve is closed for cylinder being worked on.

Comment: The problem is that I would like to clean the passage on the exhaust side of the valve as well, which goes directly to the exhaust manifold I believe.

Comment: AFAIK it is usually the egr and inlet manifold that get choked up - well it is **very** common on my make&model of car and the exhaust manifold does not seem to become an issue.

Comment: Okay I'll take that under consideration. It definitely appears that the buildup is greater towards the intake, so maybe I can just leave the exhaust side as it is.